# How to filter a field with awk follow a pattern

Tags: awk

I have a file with that format:

```
Topic:test_replication  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.ms=604800000,delete.retention.ms=86400000,cleanup.policy=delete,max.message.bytes=1000012,min.insync.replicas=2,retention.bytes=-1
Topic:teste2e_funcional PartitionCount:12   ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.00001,delete.retention.ms=86400000,cleanup.policy=delete,min.insync.replicas=2,segment.ms=604800000,retention.bytes=-1
Topic:ticket_dl.replica_cloudera    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:message.downconversion.enable=true,file.delete.delay.ms=60000,segment.ms=604800000,min.compaction.lag.ms=0,retention.bytes=-1,segment.index.bytes=10485760,cleanup.policy=delete,message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807,segment.jitter.ms=0,preallocate=false,message.timestamp.type=CreateTime,message.format.version=2.2-IV1,segment.bytes=1073741824,max.message.bytes=1000000,unclean.leader.election.enable=false,retention.ms=604800000,flush.ms=9223372036854775807,delete.retention.ms=31536000000,min.insync.replicas=2,flush.messages=9223372036854775807,compression.type=producer,index.interval.bytes=4096,min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5
```

And I want to have only the value of Topic (e.g. test_replication) and the value of min.insync.replicas (e.g. 2)

I know that it is possible to do with regular expression, but I don't know how to do it. For me the problems is that min.insync.replicas is not in the same possition so if I use the awk option -F with for example , I will got diferent values of min.insync.replicas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/Topic:[^ ]*/){
  topic=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
  match($0,/min\.insync\.replicas[^,]*/)
  print topic,substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-20)
  topic=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/Topic:[^ ]*/){                               ##Using match function to match regex Topic: till space comes here.
  topic=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)                  ##Creating topic varwhich has sub-string of current line starting from RSTART till RLENGTH.
  match($0,/min\.insync\.replicas[^,]*/)               ##Using match again to match regex frommin to till comma here.
  print topic,substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-20)          ##Printing topic and sub-string from RSTART to till RLENGTH adding and substracting respectively here.
  topic=""                                             ##Nullify variable topic here.
}
' Input_file                                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding a  `sed` solution here.

```
sed 's/Topic:\([^ ]*\).*min\.insync\.replicas=\([^,]*\).*/\1 \2/' Input_file
```

Comment: This information is helpful but if I want to had a new field like retention.ms (3 fields), I can not add new line ```match($0,/retention\.ms[^,]*/)``` before ```print```. How can I do it?

Comment: @Skiel, Could you please try following `awk 'match($0,/Topic:[^ ]*/){topic=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6);match($0,/min\.insync\.replicas[^,]*/);$(NF+1)=topic,substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-20);print;topic=""}'  Input_file` To create a new field in each line, lemme know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the questions before. Was very simple:

```
awk '
  match($0,/Topic:[^ ]*/){
  topic=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
  match($0,/min\.insync\.replicas[^,]*/)
  mininsync=substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-20)
  match($0,/retention\.ms[^,]*/)
  retention=substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)
  print topic",",mininsync,","retention 
  topic=""
}
```